# Dupulicate Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that I need to copy each day into a new tab. I need the new tab to be named with the new date and I need all of the formatting duplicated. I've been able to get it to make a new tab and rename it correctly but I cannot get it to transfer the formatting over. The cell range I need is A1:G34. Can anyone help?

I've tried doing a macro recording and it still didn't work

Comment: About `I've been able to get it to make a new tab and rename it correctly but I cannot get it to transfer the formatting over.`, can you provide your script for this?

Comment: Could you provide a a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a sheet similar to what you have with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick. You just need to change sheets name from 'Main' to which you want to copy data from and click on **⏩️ > Duplicate** at top of page next to *Help*.

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('⏩️')
      .addItem('Duplicate', 'duplicateSheet')
      .addToUi();
}

function duplicateSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh = ss.getRange("Main!A1:G34"); //Selects sheet and range you wish to copy to new sheet
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy"); // Todays date
      ss.insertSheet(date); //Creates new sheet with todays date as name
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName(date);
  var drg = dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      ssh.copyTo(drg); //Cpoies A1:G34 data from Main sheet to new sheet
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Another question, is there a script that I can add to make the new sheet/tab be in the first position? Meaning that I need the new day to show up first. This is a company vehicle sign out sheet and everything I have tried is not working.

Comment: @KristinAustin I think this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60215594/sorting-sheets-by-name-when-the-names-are-dates) could help you with sorting sheets by recent dates.